# T-SQL How to select the nearest date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a date that I am grabbing from my UI (mm/dd/year AND hh:mi) and I need to find the nearest date (one record) BEFORE the date in my UI.  I was researching, and it seems like DATEDIFF would be the best way to go about this? Or is there a better way to go about this? I'm a little unsure about the syntax. Thank you!

Comment: @Yuck - Title says `T-SQL` so I'm assuming SQL Server

Comment: Try this solution as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023145/find-closest-date-in-sql-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(DateField)
FROM Table
WHERE Datefield < DateFromUI
```

This will get you the "newest" date that is older than the one passed in the `WHERE` clause.  It should also be compatible with any RDBMS.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateColumn < 'UIDate'
ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: T-SQL syntax is `SELECT TOP (1) * ...` instead of `... LIMIT 1`.