# how to return a single record with DateTime senior status - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, join

I would do a join with two tables and get me back only one record, the one with the closest date to Now. I am not very practical sql, so if anyone can help me to compose the query. Thank you.

below a picture of all the records, I should make it just go back one, that between the two columns has given the greater, the one closest to now as mentioned earlier.

[image]

Comment: can you add your expected result  for these tables. add more details plz

Comment: I'd like to keep all of the columns and remove from the lower data records, you can?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023145/find-closest-date-in-sql-server
Or do you need to look at earlier AND later dates than today?

Comment: yes. plz check below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT RGS_Id, r.RGS_DateTime, datediff(ss,r.RGS_DateTime,GETDATE()) diff_value
    from RGS_Registrazione as r
    JOIN RGA_Allarmi as a on r.RGS_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = a.RGS_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS
    GROUP BY RGS_Id, r.RGS_DateTime) T1
ORDER BY diff_value 
LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: ok this works thanks ! i used top 1, limit 1 not work, but resolve !

Comment: 'Limit' not work with SQL Server. Try to use top key word.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Query.

```
            SELECT top 1 *
            from RGS_Registrazione as r
            join RGA_Allarmi as a on r.RGS_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = a.RGS_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS
            order by RGS_DateTime desc
```

The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.
The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set date by descending.

Please let us know if you have any que. or concerns.