# How to get single closest value for each column type in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE KEY_COLUMN='NJCRF' AND TYPE_COLUMN IN ('SCORE1', 'SCORE2', 'SCORE3') AND DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN<='2016-09-17'
```

I get about 12 record(rows) as result.

How to get result closest to DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN for each TYPE_COLUMN? In this case, how to get three records, for each type, that are closest to effective date?

UPDATE: I could use TOP if I had to go over only single type, but I have three at this moment and for each of them I need to get closest time result.

Hope I made it clear, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find closest date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023145/find-closest-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: @JacobH updated question.

Comment: Closest to w/o going over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE_COLUMN ORDER BY DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE1 t
      WHERE KEY_COLUMN = 'NJCRF' AND
            TYPE_COLUMN IN ('SCORE1', 'SCORE2', 'SCORE3') AND
            DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN <= '2016-09-17'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want *three records per type*, just use `seqnum <= 3`.

Answer (score 1):

I like `ROW_NUMBER()` for this.  You want to partition by `TYPE`, which will start the row count over for each type, then order by `DATE_EFFECTIVE desc`, and take only the highest date (the first row):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY TYPE_COLUMN ORDER BY DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN desc) RN
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE KEY_COLUMN = 'NJCRF' 
    AND TYPE_COLUMN IN ('SCORE1', 'SCORE2', 'SCORE3') 
    AND DATE_EFFECTIVE_COLUMN <= '2016-09-17'
     ) A
WHERE RN = 1
```