# Find closest second to a given datetimeoffset

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I understand that there have been many resources about this already, for example [Find closest date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023145/find-closest-date-in-sql-server) but I don't think this is a duplicate because it goes into much more depth due to the requirement.

I need to find a record closest to a given date/time/offset either in the past or in the future to the nearest second.

```
IF ( OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[MYTIMETABLE]' ) IS NOT Null )
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MYTIMETABLE];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTIMETABLE]
(
    [TIMESTAMP] datetimeoffset(0) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE]     char(3) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Fill the table with some records, in my instance, there will eventually be millions of records, hence why this requirement is a little more complicated.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

WHILE ( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[MYTIMETABLE] ) < 1000 )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Script nvarchar(max) = 
        N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTIMETABLE] ( [TIMESTAMP], [VALUE] )
        SELECT DATEADD( ' + 
        CASE ( FLOOR( ( RAND() * 4 ) + 1 ) )
            WHEN 1 THEN N'second'
            WHEN 2 THEN N'minute'
            WHEN 3 THEN N'hour'
            WHEN 4 THEN N'day'
        END + 
        N', ' + 
        CASE ( FLOOR( RAND() * 2 ) )
            WHEN 0 THEN N'-'
            WHEN 1 THEN N''
        END + 
        CONVERT( nvarchar, FLOOR( ( RAND() * 100 ) + 1 ) ) + 
        N', SWITCHOFFSET( SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), ''' + 
        CASE ( FLOOR( RAND() * 2 ) )
            WHEN 0 THEN N'-'
            WHEN 1 THEN N'+'
        END + 
        N'0' + 
        CONVERT( nvarchar, FLOOR( RAND() * 10 ) ) + 
        N':00'' ) ), ' + 
        CONVERT( nvarchar, FLOOR( ( RAND() * 100 ) + 1 ) );

--RAISERROR( @Script , 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT;

    EXEC sp_executesql @Script;
END
GO
```

The lookup script I came up with:

```
DECLARE @DateTime   datetimeoffset(0) = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();

SELECT TOP(1) [Current Time] = @DateTime, [Time Difference] = DATEDIFF( second, [TIMESTAMP], @DateTime ), * 
FROM [dbo].[MYTIMETABLE] 
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( second, [TIMESTAMP], @DateTime ) );
```

My question is, is this the most optimal version of this script?  It looks very basic and I am worried that once this goes into production and it's running thousands of lookups per day against millions of records that it's going to suffer performance problems.

The script will be housed in a function so that it can be compiled to further optimise it but any additional performance improvement advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add columns to your time table?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Are you asking if I'm able to add more columns to the table? Then yes, absolutely.

Comment: Well I would consider adding a date column to filetr the results before ordering them.

Comment: The problem is, the query could happen at 1 second past midnight on the first of January.  Meaning it's got to effectively go back to the previous year to get the closest value.